# Connecting to an H2 Database in a Docker Container

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, docker

I have a basic Spring Boot Data JPA project.  The h2 database that I'm connecting to is located at `/tmp/customerdb.h2.db`.  When running the application using `mvn spring-boot:run` everything works fine.  The application connects to the database, adds records, and prints the added records to the console.

I then build a docker container, and run it.  The docker file looks like this:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD jpa-docker-1.0.0.jar  app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar",/app.jar"]
```

When I run the container I get the following error:

```
2015-06-12 19:25:57.200  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2015-06-12 19:25:57.200 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "CUSTOMER" not found; SQL statement:
```

So it looks like the application can't see the database.  The connection URL looks like this:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/tmp/customerdb`

As I mentioned, this works fine when running outside the docker container.  I'm assuming that the line in the Dockerfile `VOLUME /tmp` creates the `/tmp` directory inside the container, along with all the files it contains, such that the database is visible, but this seems like it's not working.  Thoughts?

TIA,
- Ole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use docker [data volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/). When running your container you specify the parameter:

```
-v <host folder>:<container folder>
```

This way, the  on the host machine is mapped, inside the container

for instance:

```
docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -d yourcontainer
```

Your application inside the container looks for the file `/tmp/customerdb.h2.db`, which actually is on the host at `/tmp/customerdb.h2.db` where the db file actually exists (in general you could use different paths on the guest and the host; in your example it just happens that the host and guest folders are both on the same location "/tmp")

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution.  First I added the database docker build directory containing the `Dockerfile`.  Then I update the `Dockerfile` with the following line:

```
ADD customerdb.h2.db  /tmp/customerdb.h2.db
```

The application can now connect to the database inside the container.  Note that the database contained in the volume `/tmp/` is is confined to the container and different from the database I copied to the `/tmp/` directory on my workstation.