# Cannot access h2 database within docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, h2

https://github.com/ericus20/todo-list/issues/1#issue-476422666

I am trying to access h2 database via docker. It can be accessed successfully when running from IDE. I have tried multiple solutions which include

[H2 DB in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888995/h2-db-in-docker-container)

Creating docker volumes 
[Connecting to an H2 Database in a Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810858/connecting-to-an-h2-database-in-a-docker-container)

But I am not getting any success. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have two containers? One by your java and one by your H2 ?

Comment: No I am running it only with h2 on my classpath.

Comment: Do you want to have the h2 databse file outside docker java container?

Comment: I was wondering if it could be done via the in-memory access or file in the docker but if not, yes I would want to have a file outside the java container.

Comment: Did you solved this issue?